# Azure LUIS Ownership change

Tags: azure, bots, azure-language-understanding

How do I change the Owner? I want to be able to change the owner of the app because the other person is too busy. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you belongs to a same organization? Which role do you have on your tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Any LUIS app is defined by its Azure resources, which is determined by the owner's subscription. You have to keep in mind that **LUIS allows the transfer of ownership of your subscription but not transferring ownership of a resource**.

If you want to transfer [ownership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer) of your subscription, then you need to follow the steps below:

- **For users who have migrated** - [authoring resource migrated apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring): As the owner of the resource, you can add a `contributor`.
- **For users who have not migrated yet**: Export your app as a JSON file. Another LUIS user can import the app, thereby becoming the app owner. The new app will have a different app ID.

Also, you can move your LUIS app under these scenarios:

- [Move apps between LUIS authoring resources](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/apps-move-app-to-another-luis-authoring-azure-resource).
- [Move resource to a new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription).
- [Move resource within same subscription or across subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just after think twice, I think LUIS App Collaborator perhaps can help your problem.
Ask the owner login the app, go to **MANAGE > Application Settings > Collaborators**, just add other people as collaborator. Then other people can login the LUIS app on their own to work together.