# Http Status 410 in LUIS Cognitive Service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

We have been getting an HTTP status of 410 in production since our deployment, not in DEV

Following the directions, I re-trained then published and I still get the error 410

The URL works if we put staging=true as shown below:

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/**APP-ID**?subscription-key=**Subscription-key**&timezoneOffset=-360&q=lakeville,%20mn

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/**APP-ID**?subscription-key=**Subscription-key**&staging=true&timezoneOffset=-360&q=lakeville, mn

I have followed the instructions in the link below 
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5819c76f40a6350ce09de1ac/operations/5819c77140a63516d81aee78

My question is how do, I publish so not having staging=true in the query string will work?

The original owner of  Luis left the company and I had to scramble to get up to speed, When, I was granted permission I became the owner of the Luis service according to the collaborator page.  My appId is different then what is in production

1. Can I sync my App ID to what is in production?
2. How do we get into the other Luis (Original owner) application to publish?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59973708/9599453 for the transfer of ownership of LUIS apps.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish, select the correct slot when the pop-up window display, you could follow this tutorial:[Publish your active, trained app to a staging or production endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-publish-app).

About how to change LUIS ownership, ranusharao already provide the answer link:[Azure LUIS Ownership change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59958687/azure-luis-ownership-change/59973708#59973708).